# Delete duplicates based on certain criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has duplicate ids on it. I want to delete the duplicates based on certain criteria from the count column. Basically, only keep with ids that have the highest count. Also, if there are duplicates that all have the same value in the count column, just keep the first one.

DataFrame:

```
ID   Status     Count
12   Match       2
12   NotMatch    1
13   MaybeMatch  3
14   NotMatch    2
15   NotMatch    3
16   Match       2
16   NotMatch    1
17   Match       1
17   MaybeMatch  2
18   Match       1
18   MaybeMatch  1
18   NotMatch    1
```

Result DataFrame

```
ID   Status     Count
12   Match       2
13   MaybeMatch  3
14   NotMatch    2
15   NotMatch    3
16   Match       2
17   MaybeMatch  2
18   Match       1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort and drop duplicates:

```
res = df.sort_values('Count', ascending=False)\
        .drop_duplicates('ID')
```

If you wish to maintain ordering and include duplicate maximums:

```
g = df.groupby('ID')['Count'].transform('max')
res = df[df['Count'] == g]
```

Answer (score 0):

First sort, and then to drop duplicates and keep the first record:

```
df = df.sort_values('Count', ascending = False)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id'], keep = 'first')
```